# CQ5 - AEM - Client Context -> Customization using user profile data from Websphere Commerce

Tags: websphere, aem

I integrated the login mechanism of a CQ5 site to use the Websphere Commerce authentication, so the profiles of the users of my CQ5 site lives on Websphere Commerce, now I want that to feed the "Client Context" component with that data (User profile information on Websphere Commerce).

At this moment I got an API to retrieve from Websphere Commerce the profile information of the current user logged into my CQ5 site, but my question is how I can override and set the correct data (Websphere Commerce data) into the cookies used by the the "Client Context" component ?

Any idea of when and how the Client Context cookie "SessionPersistence" is created ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what kind of data you need to add into the client context, but it can be extender and/or customized. you basically copy the original client context and adapt it yo your needs. Adobe provides documentation for this purpose ([client context](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/client_context.html) and [client context in detail](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/client_context_detail.html))

Answer (score 0):

++ @santiagozky

You will need to write client-side JavaScript to manipulate the user profile.  And that will mean delivering your JS via a clientlib.